# If I delete Vista partition, will that break the bootloader for XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, mbr

I've got both Windows XP, Windows Vista and Ubuntu installed (on that order) on my machine, each on it's own partition. I want to recover the wasted space I've got on Vista, as I don't use it nearly as much as XP.

If I delete all the contents of the Vista partition, will it's bootloader stop working?

If I delete the Vista partition, will that kill the bootloader?

Should I delete the Vista partition, do a fix MBR from XP's recover mode and then install GRUB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Vista was installed last and removed the XP bootloader, then yes. You will have to run `fixmbr` from the recovery console on the XP install disk.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you install a bootloader in Windows XP where you erase the Vista installation from the boot order and then erase the partition?

I think you can set the bootloader with [Easy Boot CD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)

Check [this site](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Windows+XP) for more info